# How to merge HTML input box and a button? (sample images attached)

Tags: html, css

Please answer the following questions:

1. How to merge search box and search button as shown in below example1 and example2? The box and button are joined together.
2. How to put 'magnifier' icon on the left side of the search box?
3. How to put a default text into the box like 'Search for items' and fade it when user clicks on the box.

Example1 
[image: Search button and box merge]

Example2
[image]

**Example3 (I don't want a separate button as shown below)**
[image]

Please help! Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show Search Image over a Textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147934/show-search-image-over-a-textbox)

Comment: @iSumitG: Look at the source code with Firebug for Firefox or with similar tools for the other browsers.

Answer (score 10):

Easiest way is to make the entire text field wrapper, from the icon on the left to the button on the right, one div, one image.

Then put a textfield inside that wrapper with a margin-left of like 30px;

Then put a div inside the wrapper positioned to the right and add a click listener to it.

HTML:

```
<div id="search_wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="search_field" name="search" value="Search items..." />
    <div id="search_button"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#search_wrapper{
    background-image:url('/path/to/your/sprite.gif');
    width:400px;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
}

#search_field {
    margin-left:40px;
    background-transparent;
    height:40px;
    width:250px;
}

#search_button {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){

    // Click to submit search form
    $('#search_button').click(function(){
        //submit form here
    });

    // Fade out default text 
    $('#search_field').focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'Search items...')
        {
            $(this).animate({
                opacity:0
            },200,function(){
                $(this).val('').css('opacity',1);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Fade out default text can now be made with HTML5 with placeholder attribute

Answer (score 9):

For your first question, there are many ways to accomplish the joining of the button to the search box.

The easiest is to simply float both elements to the left:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input placeholder="Search items..."/>
    <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input,
button {
    float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xjozu0e/)

This method has some limitations, however, such as if you want the search box to have a percentage-based width.

In those cases, we can overlay the button onto the search box using absolute positioning.

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
}

input {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7crvn7y9/1/)

The limitation here is that the button has to be a specific width.

Probably the best solution is to use the new flexbox model. But you may have some browser support issues.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 75%;
}

input {
    flex-grow: 2;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19d6t01s/)

For your second question (adding the magnifier icon), I would just add it as a background image on the search box.

```
input {
    padding-left: 30px;
    background: url(magnifier.png) 5px 50% no-repeat;
}
```

You could also play around with icon fonts and `::before` pseudo-content, but you'll likely have to deal with browser inconsistencies.

For your third question (adding placeholder text), just use the `placeholder` attribute. If you need to support older browsers, you'll need to use a JavaScript polyfill for it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and accompanying code. Super helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It's all in the CSS... You want something like this:

http://www.red-team-design.com/how-to-create-a-cool-and-usable-css3-search-box

Also, for the search icon:

http://zenverse.net/create-a-fancy-search-box-using-css/

Src: Quick Google.

Answer (score 3):

You don't merge them, rather you give the illusion that you have. This is just CSS. Kill the search box borders, throw it all into a span with a white background and then put the fancy little dot barrier between the two things. Then toss in some border radius and you are in business.

Answer (score 1):

The above tut might look too lengthy. The basic idea is this: 
Arrange the input box just like you do. The `input` text box should be followed by the button. add the following css to do that.

```
position:relative;
top:-{height of your text box}px;
```

or you can use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="search_wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="search_field" name="search" placeholder="Search items..." />
    <div id="search_button">search</div>
</div>

#search_wrapper{
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:400px;
}

#search_field {    
    background-transparent;
    border-style: none;
    width: 350px;
}

#search_button {
    position:absolute;
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid black; 
    text-align: center;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zxcrmyyt/

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much easy if You use bootstrap with custom css
My output is diffrent but the logic works as it is..

I have used Bootstrap 5 here you can also achieve this by using Pure CSS,

```
<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-10 p-0 inputField text-center">
            <input type="text" id="cityName"placeholder="Enter your City name..">
            <input type="submit" value="search" id="submitBtn">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For Styling

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');
    
    * {
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .inputField {
        position: relative;
        width: 80%;
    }
    
    #cityName {
        width: 100%;
        background: #212529;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
    }
    
    #submitBtn {
        position: absolute;
        right: 6px;
        top: 5px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background: rgb(0, 162, 255);
        color: white;
        border-radius: 40px;
        border: none;
    }
```

Hear is an Example !
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieBEF.jpg